# fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'generator'

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

```
epochs = 150
callbacks_list=[ModelCheckpoint(save_best_only=False,filepath=checkpoint_path),TensorBoard(log_dir='logs')]
history = model.fit(generator=gen_tr,steps_per_epoch=200,
                                  epochs=epochs,
                                  validation_data=gen_val,
                                  validation_steps=1,
                                  callbacks = callbacks_list )
```

[Error message- TypeError : fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'generator'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brFlR.png)

In documentation it is written that Model.fit supports generator now, but still it shows error.

[image]

Comment: It should be `model.fit(gen_tr...)`, without keyword *generator*.

Comment: Thanks. It got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Model.fit() takes in the generator. But remove keyword generator.

```
model.fit(generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size),...)
```

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> ```
> epochs = 150
> callbacks_list=[ModelCheckpoint(save_best_only=False,filepath=checkpoint_path),TensorBoard(log_dir='logs')]
> history = model.fit(gen_tr,steps_per_epoch=200,
>                                   epochs=epochs,
>                                   validation_data=gen_val,
>                                   validation_steps=1,
>                                   callbacks = callbacks_list )
> ```
>
> (paraphrased from Frightera)

For more details you can refer [model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).